# Variable link that modifies the index of my website

Tags: php, html

I am looking for the method that allows to modify a value/text on my home page with the used link.

For example, if the URL is `mywebsite.com/index.php?name=Mike`

somewhere on my website, it will say

> "Welcome **Mike**"

If the URL is `mywebsite.com/index.php?name=Mark`, it will automatically change to

> "Welcome **Mark**"

without changing anything in my code.

Is it possible with HTML only or do I need PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with HTML, but you need JavaScript. Here's an example:

```js
// Find the query
let query = window.location.search;
// Extract the name
let match = query.match(/name=([^&]+)/);
// If the name exist, put it in the body
if (match) document.body.innerHTML = match[1];
```

Note that this won't work here, but it will work in the website.

As @JNa0 said, PHP is better suited to this task. The PHP would look like `echo $_GET["name"];`

Comment: Thanks, indeed I think I'll use PHP for this task. Could you please send me an exemple of code for php?

Comment: Something like `echo $_GET["name"];`

Comment: If the answer worked, could you please accept it? This indicates to others that it answered your question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "my link is link every redirections". This will work any time the page is reloaded with a different `name` query.

Comment: Thank you, last thing I didnt think about. How can I change my code so that my link is linked to every redirections ? 

Exemple : If the guest wants to navigate and go to another page, I want the "Welcome Mark" to stay

Comment: Just add `"?name=".$_GET["name"]` to each link. This adds the query to every link so it keeps the URL. What I would recommend is saving the name in `localStorage` with JavaScript, however.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it with JavaScript by reading `location.search` and parse it then modify the DOM (see @AlexH’s answer), but that would be overkilled for such a task. Prefer PHP (or any server-side system) when possible.